# Bash script to check if a file is modified or not

Tags: bash, shell-script

I try to write script to check if a file  was modified or not. If it did, it should `echo "Error!"`, if not - script keeps running.

My script

```
#!/bin/bash
date=$(stat -c %y)$1
while true
         do date2=$(stat -c %y$1)
                if (date2 != date)
                        echo "error!"
        done
```

Are there any errors?

Answer (score 19):

you can use `inotifywait` , [read more](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait)

> inotifywait - wait for changes to files using inotify
>
> inotifywait efficiently waits for changes to files using Linux's
>   inotify(7) interface. It is suitable for waiting for changes to files
>   from shell scripts. It can either exit once an event occurs, or
>   continually execute and output events as they occur.

use this command :

```
$ inotifywait -m -e modify /tmp/testfile
```

when i write into `testfile` , `inotifywait` alarm to me

e.g;

```
echo "bh" > /tmp/testfile
```

`inotifywait` show this message:

```
$ inotifywait -m -e modify /tmp/testfile
Setting up watches.  
Watches established.
testfile MODIFY 
testfile MODIFY
```

also you can redirect output to `while` statement :

```
while read j
do
   echo "file changed"
   break
done <  <(inotifywait -q -e modify /tmp/testfile)
```

Answer (score 6):

```bash
filename="$1"

m1=$(md5sum "$filename")

while true; do

  # md5sum is computationally expensive, so check only once every 10 seconds
  sleep 10

  m2=$(md5sum "$filename")

  if [ "$m1" != "$m2" ] ; then
    echo "ERROR: File has changed!" >&2 
    exit 1
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 3):

If you do want to 'manually' check for change in the modification timestamp, as opposed to actual difference in the contents, you need:

- `stat -c %y $1` consistently *with* the separating spaces and *inside* `$( ... )`. Even better, `stat -c %y "$1"` will work if your filename contains whitespace or any 'globbing' character
- test with classic `[ ... ]` or `test ...` and `"$var"` (because `stat %y` contains spaces; `stat %Y` would avoid that) or bash-enhanced `[[ ... ]]` which doesn't need quotes -- but not `( ... )` which does something completely different namely execute in a subshell
- some delay between loops so this doesn't completely hog your system

```
 #!/bin/bash 
 date=$(stat -c %y "$1")
 while sleep 1; do date2=$(stat -c %y "$1")
   if [[ $date2 != $date ]]; then echo "changed!"; break; fi
   # possibly exit [status] instead of break
   # or if you want to watch for another change, date=$date2
 done
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using md5sum, is safer to check real file modifications. This is script will return "The files are different" if a file diverge from the other, but when you equalize then, it will say the files are equal again.

```
#!/bin/bash

loop1(){
while sleep 1 
        do 
               md5f1=$(md5sum "$1" | cut -d' ' -f1) 
               md5f2=$(md5sum "$2" | cut -d' ' -f1)
               if [ "$md5f2" != "$md5f1" ]; then 
                    echo "The files are different now." 
                    #stop loop:
                    break 
               fi
        done
}

loop2(){ 
while sleep 1 
        do 
               md5f1=$(md5sum "$1" | cut -d' ' -f1) 
               md5f2=$(md5sum "$2" | cut -d' ' -f1)
               if [ "$md5f2" == "$md5f1" ]; then 
                    echo "The files are equal again." 
                    #stop loop:
                    break 
               fi
        done
}

while true; do 
   loop1 "$1" "$2"
   loop2 "$1" "$2"
done
```

Save it as autocompare and run like:

```
./autocompare file1 file2
```

Comment: Not i corrected it 4 mins ago.

Comment: md5sum is the right approach, but that script is far more complicated than it needs to be.  and it's comparing two different files, not just one file against possibly different versions of itself.

Comment: md5sum might not be a perfect approach if this is a particularly huge file and you plan to monitor this continually (excessive i/o and cpu usage?)